# Addition of products of (first and last), (second and last but 1) and so on numbers of an array

Tags: c, arrays, loops

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the size of array");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int array[n-1];

    printf("Enter the elements of array");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
             scanf("%d",&array[i]);
        }

    int product = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
```

Here I put the condition that, when all unique products are over then exit the loop and print the output.

```
        if(i>(n-1-i))
        {
            break;
        }
        int f = array[i];
        int l = array[n-i];

        product = product + (f*l);
    }
    printf("Result: %d",product);
    return 0;
}
```

For an array of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, I got the result as 4206199. Right Ans is 110.

Comment: Creating an array deliberately one too small seems like a bad start.  When you declare `int array[n-1];`, you only have elements `array[0]..array[n-2]` to use — yet your loop tries to write to `array[n-1]`, which is undefined behaviour because you're writing beyond the end of the array.  Remove the `-1` from the declaration.

Comment: Also accessing to `n-i` with i from 0 to n-1 doesn't feel good. Your first access is `array[n]` when maximum is n-1 (after fixing the mistake in array definition).

Comment: You also need to think about your main loop.  At the moment, you multiply and add A0 and A9, and also A9 and A0.  That doubles the sum.  However, your array size being wrong may well account for most of the rest of the trouble.  You should print the indexes and the values that are being multiplied and added so you know how the calculation proceeds, either using `printf()` statements in the code or using your debugger.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

Your program should be like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int array[n];           // Here it should be "n" not "n-1"

    printf("Enter the elements of array: ");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    int product = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(i>(n-1-i))
        {
            break;
        }
        int f = array[i];
        int l = array[n-i-1];       // Here it should be n-i-1

        product = product + (f*l);
    }
    printf("Result: %d\n",product);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty good.  It would be a good idea to check each `scanf()` call to ensure that it gets the result expected (it should return 1 each time; if it doesn't there's a problem and it is time to bail in this program).